# Bringing back an "overridden" window method

Tags: javascript

If I reset window.alert to be some other function, is there any way for me to restore it w/o first "saving" it?

For example:

```
window.alert = function() { };
```

After doing that, is there a way of restoring window.alert() to what it used to be? (btw: asking this only for "predefined" DHTML objects - not for random js objects)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
window.alert = function() { };
delete window.alert;
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKRYR/).

Comment: This returns `alert is not defined` on the second call