# Call native javascript function that has been "erased" by the web page

Tags: javascript

Let's say a web page did this:

`window.alert = console.info;`

How can I, through browser console, recover the original `alert` method to get the modal back?

I tried accessing the `window.prototype` but it does not exist. I would also like to know if such process exist in general (like, if `String.*` was erased/redefined by a website or if website made a `console.log = window.alert`).

Comment: If you can find a Polyfill for your function, you could just plug it back in. In your case, I don't think there's a polyfill for `window.alert`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bringing back an "overridden" window method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319174/bringing-back-an-overridden-window-method)

Comment: Since the dupe target that has been pointed to only contains only an outdated answer, I am more tempted to close that one as a dupe of this one...

Answer (score 3):

What you can do, is create an iframe attach it to page and then copy alert method from that iframe

```
//someone did this
window.alert = null;

//you are doing this
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(frame);
window.alert = frame.contentWindow.alert.bind(window);
document.body.removeChild(frame);
```

Comment: Would there be a way that doesn't rely on `iframe` nor on altering the page content?

Comment: You can create new window and copy alert from that [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)